# Is there a sample source code for home automation on android?

Tags: android

i wanted to know how the home automation is done in android. if anyone has a sample code of a single switch button for a light to switch on or off..??? it would be helpful for me..i wanted to know how the coding is being done of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How will you connect your light bulb up?  You need to work out what automation technologies you're going to use before asking for source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the Android market and search for 'Phidgets' you'll see application of the technology you require.